# Query String es demasiado Largo MVC

Tags: c#, mvc, web

se me está presentando el siguiente escenario:

Tengo una aplicación en C#, estoy trabajando con MVC, .Net Framework 4.5.2. Cuando quiero ejecutar en modo debug o release mi programa, me aparece el siguiente error y mensaje

> HTTP Error 404.15 - Not Found
>
> The request filtering module is configured to deny a request where the
>   query string is to long.

Me aparece un URL extremandamente largo

> http://localhost:52711/login/index?ReturnUrl=%2Flogin%2Findex%3FReturnUrl%3D%252Flogin%252Findex%253FReturnUrl%253D%25252Flogin%25252Findex%25253FReturnUrl%25253D%2525252Flogin%2525252Findex%2525253FReturnUrl%2525253D%252525252Flogin%252525252Findex%252525253FReturnUrl%252525253D%25

Además me envía esta tabla de información sobre el error:

```
Module:        RequestFilteringModule
Notification:  BeginRequest
Handler:       ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0
Error Code:    0x00000000
```

*El URL continua, pero por motivos de no volver tediosa la pregunta lo dejaré hasta ahí*.

Intento borrar todo lo que aparece después de http://localhost:52711/login/index, pero vuelve a aparecer todo el resto del URL

Ahora bien, cuando yo procedo a publicar la aplicación y configurarla en el IIS, sí me aparece bien cuando ingreso con el link a dicha página. Quiero saber sí alguien tiene alguna idea de dicho problema y como resolverlo, ya que es muy tedioso tener que hacer un cambio y tener que probarlo publicando en el IIS, en vez de poder ejecutar la página en modo debug.

Comment: Honestamente, sin ver el código es difícil saber porqué pasa eso. ¿Esa página `index` tiene alguna lógica que involucre el QueryString?

Comment: El problema es que no creo que sea problema del código, puesto que al montar la página en el IIS no aparece este error. Es el método Index de un Controlador login, el cual me devuelve la vista.

Comment: Randall, lo menciono porque el QueryString está es concatenándose a sí misma la URL. No estoy seguro de poder ayudarte, pero ¿has buscado otras problemas similares en la web? Menciono nuevamente el código porque considero importante añadir esos detalles.

Comment: Tengo la misma situacion pero no se resuelve el error al permitir anomimo en el IIS de VS estoy trabajdo con NetCore 2.2 Alguna sugerencia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Viendo el fragmento del `URL` que estas mostrando lo que me párese que esta en un ciclo de re direccionamiento infinito por lo que en cada ocasión al parámetro `ReturnUrl` le se concatena el ultimo `URL` el cual se vuele a concatenar al re direccionamiento,  el `IIS Express` del `VS` no es un `IIS` al 100% por lo que algunas funcionalidades podrían generar diferente comportamiento en uno que de otro. Lo que puedes hacer es en `VS` seleccionar el proyecto y presionar 'F4' esto te mostrara unas propiedades del `IIS Express`, habilita que acepte autenticación anónima.